# SQL server select from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables in my database **Books**, **Borrowers** and **Movement**:

**Books**

```
BookID      Title                          Author                    Category        Published
----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------- --------------- ----------
101         Ulysses                        James Joyce               Fiction         1922-06-16
102         Huckleberry Finn               Mark Twain                Fiction         1884-03-24
103         The Great Gatsby               F. Scott Fitzgerald       Fiction         1925-06-17
104         1984                           George Orwell             Fiction         1949-04-19
105         War and Peace                  Leo Tolstoy               Fiction         1869-08-01
106         Gullivers Travels              Jonathan Swift            Fiction         1726-07-01
107         Moby Dick                      Herman Melville           Fiction         1851-08-01
108         Pride and Prejudice            Jane Austen               Fiction         1813-08-13
110         The Second World War           Winston Churchill         NonFiction      1953-09-01
111         Relativity                     Albert Einstein           NonFiction      1917-01-09
112         The Right Stuff                Tom Wolfe                 NonFiction      1979-09-07
121         Hitchhikers Guide to Galaxy    Douglas Adams             Humour          1975-10-27
122         Dad Is Fat                     Jim Gaffigan              Humour          2013-03-01
131         Kick-Ass 2                     Mark Millar               Comic           2012-03-03
133         Beautiful Creatures: The Manga Kami Garcia               Comic           2014-07-01
```

**Borrowers**

```
BorrowerID  Name                      Birthday
----------- ------------------------- ----------
2           Bugs Bunny                1938-09-08
3           Homer Simpson             1992-09-09
5           Mickey Mouse              1928-02-08
7           Fred Flintstone           1960-06-09
11          Charlie Brown             1965-06-05
13          Popeye                    1933-03-03
17          Donald Duck               1937-07-27
19          Mr. Magoo                 1949-09-14
23          George Jetson             1948-04-08
29          SpongeBob SquarePants     1984-08-04
31          Stewie Griffin            1971-11-17
```

**Movement**

```
MoveID      BookID      BorrowerID  DateOut    DateIn     ReturnCondition
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------------
1           131         31          2012-06-01 2013-05-24 good
2           101         23          2012-02-10 2012-03-24 good
3           102         29          2012-02-01 2012-04-01 good
4           105         7           2012-03-23 2012-05-11 good
5           103         7           2012-03-22 2012-04-22 good
6           108         7           2012-01-23 2012-02-12 good
7           112         19          2012-01-12 2012-02-10 good
8           122         11          2012-04-14 2013-05-01 poor
9           106         17          2013-01-24 2013-02-01 good
10          104         2           2013-02-24 2013-03-10 bitten
11          121         3           2013-03-01 2013-04-01 good
12          131         19          2013-04-11 2013-05-23 good
13          111         5           2013-05-22 2013-06-22 poor
14          131         2           2013-06-12 2013-07-23 bitten
15          122         23          2013-07-10 2013-08-12 good
16          107         29          2014-01-01 2014-02-14 good
17          110         7           2014-01-11 2014-02-01 good
18          105         2           2014-02-22 2014-03-02 bitten
```

What is a query I can use to find out which book was borrowed by the oldest borrower?

I am new to SQL and am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: Sounds a lot like homework...

Comment: Hi. Did you tried something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two different solutions:

First using two [sub querys](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm) and one [equi-join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Equi-join):

```
select Title
from Books b , Movement m
where b.BookID = m.BookID and m.BorrowerID = (select BorrowerID
                                              from Borrowers
                                              where Birthday = (select MIN(Birthday)
                                                                from Borrowers))
```

Using two equi-joins and one sub query:

```
select Title
from Books b, Borrowers r, Movement m
where b.BookID = m.BookID
and m.BorrowerID = r.BorrowerID
and Birthday = (select MIN(Birthday) from Borrowers)
```

Both above queries give the following answer:

```
Title
------------------------------
Relativity
```